# Animation Effect css

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm just playing around with animation in css.

This is the code that i'm writing...

The html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
     <div class="item-1"></div>
     <div class="item-2"></div>
     <div class="item-3"></div>
     <div class="item-4"></div>
     <div class="item-5"></div>
     <div class="item-6"></div>
 </div>
```

And the css:

```
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    width: fit-content;
    grid-template-columns: 150px 150px 150px;
    grid-template-rows: 150px 150px;
    grid-gap: 1rem;
    position: relative;
}

.wrapper>div {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, crimson, yellow);
    border: 5px solid #555;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}

.item-6 {
    animation-name: playthis;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-iteration-count: initial;
}

@keyframes playthis {
    0% {
        width: 100%;
    }

    50% {
        width: 400%;
    }

    100% {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

So is just a simple animation, but i'm trying to figure it out how I could achieve a certain effect and that is: when the box reaches 400% width, let the right border remain fixed in that position and then return to its original size... as if the right border drags the left to itself...
I hope i was clear!

Comment: If the width reverts the "border" cannot remain in place as it's at the end of the element.

Comment: Unfortunately as it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a possible solution using `margin-left`.

```css
:root{
  --maxWidth: 200%;
  --finalWidth: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  width: fit-content;
  grid-template-columns: 150px 150px 150px;
  grid-template-rows: 150px 150px;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper>div {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, crimson, yellow);
  border: 5px solid #555;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.item-6 {
  animation-name: playthis;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-iteration-count: initial;
}

@keyframes playthis {
  0% {
    width: var(--finalWidth);
  }
  50% {
    width: var(--maxWidth);
    margin-left: 0%
  }
  100% {
    width: var(--finalWidth);
    margin-left: calc(var(--maxWidth) - var(--finalWidth));
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item-1"></div>
  <div class="item-2"></div>
  <div class="item-3"></div>
  <div class="item-4"></div>
  <div class="item-5"></div>
  <div class="item-6"></div>
</div>
```

The margin-left value in the last key frames can be calculated using the `width` of your object like this:

```
maxWidth - finalWidth
```

Where `maxWidth` is the width at 50% of your animation and `finalWidth` the width at the end of your animation. To simplify the use of the code, I used css variables and calculate the final `margin-left`